# Selecting multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, select, multiple-columns, vba

I am currently working on a project at my work which requires good understanding of Excel. For this project I have to design an Excel template and I am currently working on this.

I have some knowledge of how to use Excel, but that does not contain coding in Excel by using VBA.

I have found some code on the internet which is not fully helping me with my issue. My issue is that I want to hide some columns based on the outcome of a function in one cell. As you can see below, I already created some code, but after trying everything I still could not manage to hide multiple columns. I have found some solutions on the internet to select multiple columns, but unfortunately, I could not manage to use it in my code. Please let me know if you have any solutions for my issue. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("B5").Value = "USD" Then
        Columns("C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("B5").Value = "LC" Then
        Columns("C").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the code that helped me with my issue. Thanks to the users Pᴇʜ and sous2817. Hope that this may help someone else.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("B5").Value = "USD" Then
        Union(Columns("C"), Columns("E")).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("B5").Value = "LC" Then
        Union(Columns("C"), Columns("E")).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably several ways to solve your issue.  When interacting with more than one row or column, you need to use the `Range` property.  Here is one way (assuming a contiguous range):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("B5").Value = "USD" Then
        Range("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("B5").Value = "LC" Then
        Range("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, as Pᴇʜ points out in the comments, it might be better to use the Change event as you only really care if / when B5 changes.  The `SelectionChange` event probably fires more than you need it to (again, pending on your sheet setup).  Here is the same code using a different event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$5" Then
        If Target.Value = "USD" Then
            Range("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "LC" Then
            Range("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If       
End Sub
```

Just to complete the overall ask, here is a way to go about the same task with non-contiguous range(s):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$5" Then
        If Target.Value = "USD" Then
            Union(Columns("C"), Columns("G")).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "LC" Then
            Union(Columns("C"), Columns("G")).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Additionally if B5 is **not a formula** you can use the `Worksheet_Change` event (instead of `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event) in combination with `If Target.Address = "$B$5" Then` to trigger hide/show only when the value in B5 changes and not everytime the cell selection changes, which should be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried this code and it works great, however, could you please let me know how I can select different columns (e.g. columns C and G). Thank you

Comment: @Ali With `Union()` like `Union(Columns("C"), Columns("G")).EntireColumn.Hidden = True`. Works also with ranges `Union(Range("C:E"), Columns("G"))`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, thank you for your advice. This is actually what I sought. However, unfortunately, the code is not working automatically. I did not mention it earlier, but cell B5 is indeed the outcome of a formula. If I fill in LC or USD, then the columns C and G are hidden/unhidden. However, nothing happens in case case B5 is a formula.

Comment: As I mentioned already the `Worksheet_Change` event doesn't work if B5 is the outcome of a formula. Then you can only use the `SelectionChange` event.

Comment: Yes you mentioned that. I could not include in my previous message the code I came up with. So I have amended the code, but unfortunately, it is not working.

Comment: @Ali Please no full code in comments, that's unreadable. Use the `SelectionChange` event without the `If Target.Address = "$B$5" Then` so that it runs on **every** selection change, otherwise it only runs if you select cell B5.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, thank you very much for your help. I indeed noticed that this code only works if I select cell B5. Now I am trying to follow up your advice, but unfortunately, it is still not working. I use the `SelectionChange event` and I have worked on all kind of combinations without any result. Could you please help me with this. Thank you

Comment: just take the code of the first code block in the answer above and adjust `Range("C:D")` to `Union(Columns("C"), Columns("G"))`. That's all. Note that the code has to be in the scope of a specific worksheet not in a module!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, much appreciate your help. It is working now. :)

Comment: @AsZ Please consider marking the answer as solution.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, I actually wanted to do that, but it is mentioned that I have to wait one day before I can consider the answer as solution. Will definitely do that tomorrow.Thanks